# Data summary with DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, datatables

Hello cordial greetings I have a problem when doing an activity.

What I would like to do is a summary of data in a new table that according to the person in charge shows me the activity count: I show an image of how I want to show it:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y87Aq.png)

obtaining from the data that I have in my main table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oio9I.png)

I use laravel where by means of a controller I obtain the data of my main table and This is my script to implement the datatable

```js
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var tableadmin = $('#admin').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSider: true,
      ordering: false,
      "pageLength": 10,
      "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]],
      "autoWidth": false,
      "language":{
        "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
      }
    });
    //FILTERS
    $('.filter-input').keyup(function(){
      tableadmin.column($(this).data('column'))
      .search($(this).val())
      .draw();
    });
    $('.filter-select').change(function(){
      tableadmin.column($(this).data('column'))
    .search($(this).val())
    .draw();
    });
    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    var offices = $('input:checkbox[name="adm"]:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join('|');
    tableadmin.column(7).search(offices, true, false, false).draw();
    });
    //FIN FILTERS
  });
</script>
```

Could you tell me or guide me on how to implement this new chart, thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Suggestion: You can [edit] your question to show us the source data used to populate the existing table. For example, show us the JSON (if it is sourced from JSON). But really, I would recommend summarizing the data directly from its source (e.g. using SQL, if the data is stored in a relational database).

Comment: What would probably be a bad idea (in my opinion) is attempting to pull the data from one HTML table to build the summary table. But my comments involve guesses and assumptions, because the question does not provide much information.

Comment: ok now I will make the updates

Comment: Another quick note: The question uses `serverSider: true`. I assume you meant `serverSide: true` - however, that is not a valid option to use if you are not also using a DataTables Ajax data source).